# Is there a way to acces all levels of inheritance with a pointer to a base class?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Given the following example:

```
    class Base
    {
    public:
        virtual void PrintSomething();
    }
    Base::PrintSomething()
    {
        printf("A\n");
    }

    class DerivedOne : public Base
    {
    public:
        void PrintSomething();
    }
    DerivedOne::PrintSomething()
    {
        printf("B\n");
    }

    class DerivedTwo : public DerivedOne
    {
    public:
        void PrintSomething();
    }
    DerivedTwo::PrintSomething()
    {
        printf("C\n");
    }

    main()
    {
        DerivedOne *pOne = new DerivedTwo();
```

I can access every `PrintSomething()` function.

```
        pTwo -> PrintSomething();
        pTwo -> DerivedTwo::PrintSomething();
        pTwo -> Base::PrintSomething();

        Base *pBase = new DerivedTwo();
```

I can only access `Bases` and `DerivedTwo` functions

```
        pBase -> PrintSomething();
        pBase -> Base::PrintSomething();

        pBase -> DerivedOne::PrintSomething(); //Error: DerivedOne is not a base of Base
    }
```

Comment: From just a pointer to a base type and without casting? Short answer: No. Long answer: Nope.

Comment: That's not how inheritance and dynamic polymorphism works.

Comment: Got it, thanks. How do I choose a correct answer now?

Comment: So this is like trying to point with a derived class pointer to a base object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `DerivedOne::PrintSomething` to be called, then `pBase` should be initialized with a `DerivedOne` pointer. Otherwise you are doing it all wrong. Also please use `std::unique_ptr` or any other smart pointer.

Comment: I do, I just used regular pointers in the example to make it easier to read (and type). I don't need (yet) to do what I asked. I was just messing with classes and pointers to learn and the question came up.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeffrey.

```
DerivedTwo *pBase = new DerivedTwo();
pBase -> Base::PrintSomething();
pBase -> DerivedOne::PrintSomething();
pBase -> PrintSomething();
```

It would work.

If you do this:

```
Base *pBase = new DerivedTwo();
```

Then pBase holds the virtual pointer of DerivedTwo class virtual table, therefore it can access the PrintSomething of DerivedTwo class.

Though you can call DerivedOne::PrintSomething() from inside the DerivedTwo::PrintSomething() function like:

```
void DerivedTwo::PrintSomething()
{
    DerivedOne :: PrintSomething();
    printf("C\n");
}
```